# How to verify if either 200 or 201 status code in Frisby Test

Tags: javascript, rest, jasmine, jasmine-node, frisby.js

I'm using `frisby` v0.8.5 and `jasimine-node`.  With `frisby` there's the following to assert for expected return http status code:

```
 f = frisby.create(/*stuff....*/);
 ...
 ... 
 f.expectStatus(200);
 f.toss();
```

This works fine if the endpoint has a single expected status, but in some cases (like a POST endpoint) you might get back a `201` for created or a `200` if the resource is already present.

Is there any way in frisby to check for on of several acceptable response status codes?

Comment: It seems you need to check both results, if I understand your question correctly, this would be the implementation in jasmine:
I'd suggest using a pattern like this:

    var result = myFunction();
    var reachedSuccessfulStatus = (status === 200 || result === 201);

    expect(reachedSuccessfulStatuse).toBe(true);

I found it here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jasmine-js/IyJMTzpzFBc, don't know how to do this in frisby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found an easy way to do this using the `after()` and native jasmine matching functionaly.

The general idea is since Frisby is asynchronous, you need to check the result after it's been tossed and caught.  Inside the raw result, you can manually verify the status code against a regular expression, which in this case is either 200 or 201:

```
 f = frisby.create(/*stuff....*/);
 // ...
 // ... 

 f.after( function(err, res, body) {

     //Look for either a 200 or 201
     expect(res.statusCode).toMatch(//20[0|1]/);

 });

 f.toss();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra method to `Firsby lib`, by creating local file `xyz.coffee` that will be required `xyz = require "./xyz"` there you can provide:

```
Frisby = Object.getPrototypeOf(frisby.create())

Frisby.expectStatuses = (statuses) ->
  @current.expects.push =>
    expect(statuses).toContain(@current.response.status)
  return this
```

Eventually you can always copy paste, the above, to your `spec.coffee` file
After all, simply use in you script:

```
.expectStatuses([200, 201])
```

It does the job perfectly.

Comment: Frisby does not have an `expectStatuses()` method.  Only `expectStatus()`

Comment: @Ray mea culpa - I've adjusted my response